# Mongo schema friends relations with properties

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, spring-data

Contemplating on my Mongo schema design...

I want to represent friends relations between profiles these relations should contain properties not only reference.

Thought about the following simple ***profile*** document:

```
{
  "pid:"profileId"
  "friends":[
   {
     "friendId":"friendId"
     "isCloseFriend": "true/false"
     "points":"points"
   },
    {
     "friendId":"friend2Id"
     "isCloseFriend": "true/false"
     "points":"points"
   } .....]
}
```

I need to be able to do the following:

1) for a given profile I need to retrieve all the profiles which has at least one common close friend and the common close friends(or reference) in the same result set.

2) retrieve the top X of my friends order by points..including the points in the result set.

What is the right way to perform these use-cases by queries / map-reduce? and how...

Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some of the queries you've tried, but can't get to work.

Comment: For point 1, you will need to use multiple queries. For point 2) look at the aggregation framework

Comment: +1 for aggregation framework - it will be a lot faster than mapreduce and simpler to use. Once you see what it allows you to do please reconsider your schema - it's not a good idea for performance to have continuously growing documents.  On the other hand if you plan to cap the length of the array (only keep your top 10 close friends; or only allow you to have max-50 friends or some such) then you should state that in your schema description as it makes a difference.